# How do you use a string for a button, but only the first 10 characters

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button, with the ID button1.
When you click the button, it opens another activity, where you can enter in text, when you press the back button again, it saves the text and displays is on the button. But I only want the first 10 or so characters to show on the button. Is this possible?

Here is some code:

```
Button item1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        item1.setText(PrefConnector.readString(this, PrefConnector.ONE, null));
```

The conect of the string `PrefConnector.readString(this, PrefConnector.ONE, null)` is very long, about a paragraph. So I only want the first 10 characters to appear on the button, and if possible an ellipse on the end to show that there is more text.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the String itself use `substring()`:

```
String ellipsed = PrefConnector.readString(this, PrefConnector.ONE, null);
if(ellipsed.length() > 10)
    ellipsed = ellipsed.substring(0, 10) + "...";
item1.setText(ellipsed);
```

Alternatively, you should also be able to define a maximum width in your Button's XML and allow it to use ellipses when necessary:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxWidth="50dp" />
```

Comment: This works great, but what if the string is empty, the one you are trying to load. IE, doesn't have 10 characters in it?

Comment: Good catch, this is the exact reason I posted the XML alternative. The XML will add the ellipse only when necessary. However you can check for this in Java too, it just requires a couple extra lines.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking that. Will a simple IF statement do for this?

Comment: can I ask one more thing. What is the string has no content?

Comment: This is my code but it isn't working,
`Button item1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontext1);
  String ellipsed = PrefConnector.readString(this, PrefConnector.ONE, null);
  if(ellipsed.length() < 1)
   ellipsed = "Touch to edit";
  if(ellipsed.length() > 10)
      ellipsed = ellipsed.substring(0, 10) + "...";
  
  item1.setText(ellipsed);`

Comment: "it isn't working" is too vague. Does it crash or does your Button have no text? Use your debugger or LogCat statements to see what `ellipsed` holds.